# Do not bind empty string to Repeater Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-3.5

I am binding string array to the Repeater Control,

```
string[] strPageSize = new string[25];

repPageSize.DataSource = strPageSize;
repPageSize.DataBind();
```

.aspx Page Code

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repPageSize" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>                    
                    <a href="#" id="lnkPageIndex" rev="pageIndex" runat="server" onserverclick="lnkPageIndex_Click"><%#(string) (Container.DataItem)%></a>
                </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:Repeater>
```

but this string array may contains the `null` or `empty` string,and i don't want to bind them to my control.How i can avoid this.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LINQ.Extensions namespace like this:

```
string[] strPageSize = new string[25];

repPageSize.DataSource = strPageSize.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s));
repPageSize.DataBind();
```